# If $A$ is infinite set, than $P(A)$ is infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I want to prove, while using infinite sets definition, that:

If $A$ is infinite set, than $P(A)$ is infinite.

: Because A is infinite, there exists a subset $S \subset A$ such that there exists a bijection function $f:A \to S$.

Let $B \subset P(A)$. I try to define a function $g:P(A) \to B$.

I really don't know how to define $g$ function.

Any help on how to continue my proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you state precisely the definition you use for an infinite set?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I mean, proving that there exists a bijection function $g: P(A) \to B$, proving the containment, and the bijection.

Comment: That was not my question. My question was that you write in your post the definition you use for a set to be infinite.

Comment: A set is define to be infinite set, if it has the same cardinality as a subset of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose an appropriate $B\subsetneq P(A)$.

**Hint:** Use $f$ to define a bijection between $P(S)$ and $P(A)$.

Comment: Thank you, I don't see why does this help me, and I failed proving it...

Comment: Let $B:=P(S)$, it's a proper subset of $P(A)$.

Comment: Oh I see, so let $$g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x & x \in S \\
\left \{ f(x) \right \} & x \notin S
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Something like that?

Comment: Or maybe, $g(x) = \left \{ f(x) \right \}$ ?

Comment: Something like this. $g(X):=\{f(x):x\in X\}\subseteq S$.

Comment: What do you mean by big $X$ ? Thanks!

Comment: You want a function $P(A)\to P(S)$. So, $X$ runs over $P(A)$, that is, $X\subseteq A$.

Comment: Thank you my friend, unfortunately I do not understand the function that you defined...